# Can't add a 3D subview to the view of the controller

Tags: view, swift, scenekit

I have a problem when i want to add a 3D subview to my controller view. I can't see the 3D subview. Is the code of GameControllerView class :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("Start the game")

    // Model
    cubeData = CubeData()
    /*
    let viewTest = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view = viewTest
    */

    // 3D view position
    let sizeScnView = CGSize(width: 350.0, height: 350.0)
    let centerView = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame) - sizeScnView.width/2, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame) - sizeScnView.height/2)
    scnView = GameSceneView(frame: CGRect(origin: centerView, size: sizeScnView))

    // add 3D view
    self.view.addSubview(scnView)

    // don't allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    scnView.showsStatistics = false

    // Start Accelerometer
    self.motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    self.startAccelerometer()

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

With this code i can't see my GameSceneView which is a subclass of SCNView (3D view). But if I delete comments of the viewTest variable (just below cubeData) my GameSceneView is displayed but without the content of my controller view.

Question : Why 3D subview can't appear on the controller view ?

EDIT : I just noticed that the 3D view is behind the controller view background. How can I add my 3D view over the background contained in view controller ?

Answer (score 0):

If your superview is GPU-rendered (i.e. a SceneKit or SpriteKit view), there may be issues with having GPU-rendered subviews. One solution may be to make what's currently your view controller's `view` into a subview, so that your `scnView` is a sibling view to it, and use [`insertSubview:aboveSubview`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:aboveSubview:) or a related method to layer them.